# How to handle X-ing out of a pop up in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am very new to using `python` and `tkinter` in general, but I was hoping to get some guidance on how to handle `toplevel` pop up exits. I have wrote a pop up that once would disable a `button` in the `root` level unless all the checkboxes in the pop up window are checked, and the close `button` is clicked.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to handle users "X-ing out" (closing via clicking the x icon top right corner of pop ups) instead of closing the pop via the `button` I made. (The `button` has the command .`destroy()` and handles toggling the status of the `button` on `root` level).

Comment: To clarify, you want to prevent the user from being able to close your toplevel window with the X button? Is that what you are asking? You could definitely handle that and prevent the window from closing until they address your conditions. Something like `self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", your_function)` where `your_function` would manage what happens when they try to close it with the X button.

Comment: @Rory Thank you so much for your reply, this actually answered the question for me I just simply did not know the `self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", your_function)` part this is allowing me to handle the event perfectly. Thank you!!!